# role of virtual and protected in this code?

Tags: c#

In following code, in the derived class from `ArrayList` we are using a method as `OnChanged()`.

This class is declared as:   `protected virtual void OnChanged(EventArgs e)`

Question: what is the purpose behind **protected** and **virtual** keywords?

Anyway it would work but I need to know the purpose behind using protected access modifier and virtual. One last thing this code is from MSDN page teaching how to user delegates to kick an event.

```
using System;

namespace DelegateForEvents
{
    using System.Collections;

    // A delegate type of hooking up change notificatins.
    public delegate void ChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

    // A class that works just like ArrayList, but sends notifications whevern the list changes.
    public class ListWithChangedEvent : ArrayList
    {
        // An event that clients can use to be notified whenever the elements of the list change
        public event ChangedEventHandler Changed;

        // Invoke the Changed event; called whenever list changes 
        protected virtual void OnChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Changed != null)
                Changed(this, e);
        }


        // Override some of the methods that can change the list;
        // Invoke event after each
        public override int Add(object value)
        {
            int i = base.Add(value);
            OnChanged(EventArgs.Empty);

            return i;
        }

        public override void Clear()
        {
            base.Clear();
            OnChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        public override object this[int index]
        {
            //get
            //{
            //    return base[index];
            //}
            set
            {
                base[index] = value;
                OnChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}


namespace TestEvents
{
    using DelegateForEvents;

    class EventListener
    {
        private ListWithChangedEvent List;

        public EventListener(ListWithChangedEvent list)
        {
            List = list;
            // Add "ListChanged" to the Changed event on "List"
            List.Changed += new ChangedEventHandler(ListChanged);
        }

        // This will be called whenever the list changes.
        private void ListChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is called when the event fires");
        }

        public void Detach()
        {
            // Death the event and delete the list
            List.Changed -= new ChangedEventHandler(ListChanged);
            List = null;
        }
    }

    class Test
    {

        // Test the ListWithChangedEvent class
        static void Main()
        {
            // Create a new list
            ListWithChangedEvent list = new ListWithChangedEvent();

            // Create a class that listens to list's change event
            EventListener listener = new EventListener(list);

            // Add and remove items from the list.
            list.Add("item 1");
            list.Clear();
            listener.Detach();
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's probably a MSDN page teaching those keywords too.

Comment: You should never use non-generic collection classes.

Comment: @millimoose is that all you know? I have my own thoughts that I asked about them. I am just tired of people who drop a comment and leave without understanding the whole picture. Feel free to decrement it again or ask you friends to help you

Comment: @amit what about people who drop a question without doing some very basic reading?

Comment: @Blorgbeard, did you see my question in below? again I know what virtual or ... other access modifiers do ... I was trying to get to a point which you and few other don't let me ask.  Thanks anyway

Comment: millimoose doesn't have any friends

Comment: FWIW, this is also the standard pattern for raising an event: a protected virtual void OnXXX function that takes an EventArgs and raises the XXX event.

Comment: is there any URL that I can read about it? thanks

Comment: @amitkohan Your phrasing didn't really make that very clear. Also, there's no magic point behind using the keywords *in this context*. They do here exactly what they do anywhere. What they mean is that whoever wrote the code sample wanted to let eventual subclasses override the handler. This is a very common way of handling events on the current object, so the documentation is teaching it "by osmosis".

Comment: @amitkohan This is *design guideline* explicitly outlined here: [Event Design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229011(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @amitkohan (Next time consider investing the time you put into moping into actually making your question clear and not including 50 lines of mostly irrelevant example code. Instead you expect people to read your mind and follow comments on other answers. The ["edit"](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12829367/edit) link is useful for the latter.)

Comment: I accept the fact that I did not explain it clearly and you are right about it but I would definitely fix it if I was not caught up with other things. I will look at your link and thanks for sharing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual: this method is intended to  be overridden. When calling this method, generate 'callvirt' rather than 'call' in the IL.

Protected: this method is visible to classes which inherit from this one, but is not publicly callable.

Comment: right all were said by you and other experts I know but what is point of using it when it still runs and works? that was the bottom line I was trying get to.

Comment: callvirt means that there will never be a case of the runtime resolving the call from a derived class that implements this method and calling the base class.

Protected means that derived objects can call the method. 

Without these, it wouldn't work.

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're trying to get out of this question. Flagging to close.

Comment: fine with me. I will ask to close it

Answer (score 1):

`protected` means that the method can be used in derived classes but is not visible for outsiders. Sort of like `private` with an exception for derived classes.

`virtual` means that regardless of the variable type on which the method is called it's always the actual object instance's method that is called.

Comment: are you sure about protected definition here? I

Answer (score 1):

virtual methods mean that a subclass can override the implementation of the base class. The virtual keyword basically "turns on" polymorphism.

Protected means the method is only accessible by the base and derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

`protected` is an access modifier that defines a member as accessible from within the class in which it is declared, and from within any class derived from the class that declared this member.

`virtual` denotes that a function can be overridden by a derived class.  This means that if you had another class that inherited from `ListWithChangedEvent` it could change what `OnChanged` does.